# Understanding Crashlytics missing dsyms report

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using Firebase Crashlytics to track crashes on my iOS app.
In *Missing dsyms's* dashboard I see one UUID which has more than 50,000 crashes, but others UUIDs display something about 1-60 crashes. What does it mean? Why one UUID may have so many crashes?
Maybe am I understand the report in the wrong way?

I started to suspect that some malefactor runs some sort of automation using my app, maybe it runs scripts to check all the calls to API or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric/Firebaser here - you can look at the names of the dSYM files themselves to see where the "missing crashes" are coming from. Oftentimes we see one or two dSYMs of a larger app have the majority of the crashes, since the majority of the app code is often contained under one or two frameworks. This might have some more insight: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

This count will also include non-fatal events that you're logging to Crashlytics yourself as well, so if you have a high count of those, it could make that number appear larger. If you have any specific concerns about your dSYMs, you can always reach out to support@fabric.io with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Download the dSYMs.zip file from Google Chrome. If you download the dSYMs file from safari it will decompress the zip file and give you a dSYMs folder. But we need the dSYMs.zip file which you will get by downloading the dSYMs.zip file from Google Chrome.

Open AppStore Connect https://appstoreconnect.apple.com.
-Go to My Apps
-Select your app
-Click on the Activity tab from the top
-Expand/Select your version
-Find and click 'Download dSYM' button

it will download the zip file